# Constructing HICON with multiple images from memory pixel data

Tags: windows, winapi, gdi

is there a Win32 API to construct a HICON handle that contains icons in multiple sizes from pixel data stored in memory? I know that I can construct single icons from memory pixel data using CreateIconIndirect() but these icons will always contain just one size but I want to construct a single HICON handle that contains icons in 16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 48x48 and 256x256 for use with RegisterClassEx().

I know I could simply use a resource icon or load an external *.ico but that's all not possible for my specific case. I need to be able to construct this multiple image HICON from memory pixel data.

The only solution that comes to my mind is to create a temporary *.ico file on disk and then load it using LoadIcon() but that is not a nice solution.

That's why I'd like to ask if there's an API to construct a multi-image HICON from memory pixel data?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think that HICON contains all icons?

Comment: Because RegisterClassEx() only gets a single HICON handle from me and still Windows uses different icons for my application depending on the context (taskbar icon, tab cycling icon, window border icon...). Windows seems to get this all from the single HICON handle I pass to RegisterClassEx() so there must be multiple images in it.

Comment: No WNDCLASSEX use two hicons - normal and small.

Comment: @What may see? I am wrote exactly thing as David.

Comment: I just meant to say that discussion goes on below ;)

Comment: Icons created from resources [remember what resource they came from](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/08/20/8880062.aspx) and can go back to the original resource if resizing is needed. Icons created from memory have nowhere to go back to.

Comment: @Raymond: I see, seems like I wasn't that wrong after all then ;) So actually there are some special kinds of HICON handles. Xearinox and David Heffernan are right in that these HICON handles contain only one image *but* they contain links to other images, so I'd say that *de facto* they could be said to contain multiple images. So a better version of my question would have been: "How to construct HICON handles that contain links to other images from memory pixel data." But I guess there's no way except creating a temporary *.ico on disk and load this.

Answer (score 1):

No there is not. An `HICON` contains a single image. There is no such thing as a multi-image `HICON`.

You can supply two separate icons when you call `RegisterClassEx`. You supply both large and small icons in the `WNDCLASSEX` structure. Which is all you need because the only icons that are associated with a window are the large and small icons.

Comment: Actually I just set the hIcon member of WNDCLASSEX. I set it to LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1)). IDI_ICON1 contains many different icon sizes. So how should Windows know which icon to load here? The call to LoadIcon() cannot know that the resulting HICON is being passed to WNDCLASSEX.hIcon. So how should it know to load a 32x32 size and not a 256x256 size?

Comment: @Andreas: Read msdn doc for LoadImage.

Comment: You need to use `LoadImage` rather than `LoadIcon`.

Comment: I'd rather like to understand the behaviour I see here. I've been using LoadIcon() with WNDCLASSEX for 12+ years. So what size will this LoadIcon() call load then? The icon resource IDI_ICON1 contains many different sizes. Will it just load the first icon size in the resource then?

Comment: The documentation has the answer: *LoadIcon can only load an icon whose size conforms to the SM_CXICON and SM_CYICON system metric values. Use the LoadImage function to load icons of other sizes.*

Comment: Alright, then the behaviour makes sense. So I guess Windows takes the icons displayed in the taskbar and tab cycling from the executable directly and not from the handle passed to RegisterClassEx(). Thanks for clearing this up. I've really thought for all those years that a HICON can hold multiple images.

Comment: No it does not take the icons from the executable. It takes them from the window associated with the taskbar button. You can call `WM_SETICON` to change the icon associated with a window, and see the change in the taskbar.

Comment: But I never call WM_SETICON and in the taskbar Windows uses a larger icon from IDI_ICON1 in comparison to a smaller one from IDI_ICON1 for my window's border! So where should this taskbar icon come from then? The only call I ever do is the LoadIcon() for RegisterClassEx() and this loads only a single icon of size SM_CXICON and SM_CYICON. So where does the larger image in the taskbar come from? It really must come directly from the executable if LoadIcon() can only load a single image....

Comment: If you only supply one icon, the system scales it when it needs the other icon. You should supply both large and small.

Comment: No, it's definitely not a scaled version. There are different icons in the taskbar and the window border bar although I'm just setting hIcon of WNDCLASSEX. CreateWindowEx() takes an hInstance as an argument so CreateWindowEx() probably loads the bigger icon from the executable resource.

Comment: I think this is now a little off the original topic.

Comment: Also see above (comment by Raymond Chen). It seems like there are *de facto* multi image HICON handles. Yes, they contain only a single image but they have some sort of linking functionality attached which allows Windows to get larger images through a single HICON handle. That's why I think it could be said that *de facto* HICON handles can have multiple images.

Comment: That is quite interesting.